# Rails generate scaffold no longer generate .jbuilder files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffold

I've created custom templates for my model record and views however now the .jbuilder files are no longer generated in views/

below screenshot of my lib folder
What should i change to have the jbuilder files generated?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

from 
`rails g scaffold --help` documentation,
to generate the jbuilder files you need to pass the `--jbuilder` option.

Note that the jbuilder files should be generated by default, so make sure that the jbuilder gem is installed first.

You can also generate the jbuilder files alone with:

`rails g jbuilder [model name]`